# GoogleCloud SSH in Browser stopped working

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh

Google SSH in Browser stopped working

I get the following error

`SSH authentication has failed In order to debug, please analyze the /var/log/auth.log file on the target machine using the serial console. Reading the recent serial port output may also be helpful.`

I can't open the auth.log file cause I can't get into the instance.

When I try using serial I get the following error

```
Connection Failed
We are unable to connect to the VM on port 22.

Please ensure that VM has a firewall rule that allows TCP ingress traffic from the IP range 0.0.0.0/0, port: 22.
In case you prefer to allow SSH connections for the narrower IP range, please consider using Identity-Aware-Proxy (IAP).
```

Comment: You have an error and a recommendation. What steps did you follow to debug the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can't log into that again. Please create a new VM and start everything from scratch.

**But when you logout, please ensure that port 22 is open through the firewall.**